# Selecting individual locations and adding them to a model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst

Am currently trying to build a model where you can add an extra location to a delivery route and the model outputs the quickest route between all them all. I have a shapefile that contain 111 locations of customers address across a city. What feature/process do I have to add to the model to enable the user of the model to select individual locations from the shapefile so that it is added to the route.

Comment: Select the locations first then pass them to the model.  Most tools will typically run on a selection set if there is one present.

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps investigate using a feature set to request user input of coordinate information.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Midavalo you could:

> Select the locations first then pass them to the model. Most tools
>   will typically run on a selection set if there is one present.

or alternatively, perhaps investigate using a feature set to request user input of coordinate information.